# Returning mutated object with some key modified using spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, spread

In the below object, I want to increment the value of data[1]'s val by 1, and leave everything unchanged, how can I achieve it?

```
const state = 
    {
        "data": [{
                "val": 1,
                "other": 10
            },
            {
                "val": 11,
                "other": 100
            },
            {
                "val": 100,
                "other": 1000
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want the mutated object to be like this-

```
{
    "data": [{
            "val": 1,
            "other": 10
        },
        {
            "val": 10,
            "other": 100
        },
        {
            "val": 100,
            "other": 1000
        }
    ]
}
```

I know that I can change the value directly like this- `state.data[1].val = state.data[1].val+1`, but I want to achieve the same using spread operator, is it possible to achieve it using spread operator?
Somthing like this-

```
const mutatedState = {
        ...state,
        data: [...state.data]
}
```

Comment: Working with deep objects and immutability can be a real pain so something like lodash's functional programming helpers can make your life much easier. look up:
lodash/fp/set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the `data` out of the object. And use like this

```js
const state = { "data": [{ "val": 1, "other": 10 }, { "val": 11, "other": 100 }, { "val": 100, "other": 1000 } ] }
    
const {data} = state;         
let res = {
            ...state,
            data:[
                    data[0],
                    {...data[1],val:data[1].val+ 1},
                    ...data.slice(2)
                 ]
          }
 
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could assign parts of the array/objects.

```js
var object = { data: [{ val: 1, other: 10 }, { val: 10, other: 100 }, { val: 100, other: 1000 }] },
    result = {
        ...object,
        data: Object.assign(
            [...object.data],
            {
                1: Object.assign(
                    {},
                    object.data[1],
                    { val: object.data[1].val + 1 }
                )
            }
        )
    };

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

With a bit help of some functional helpers that is actually quite elegant:

```
 const mapOne = (index, mapper) => array => array.map((it, i) => i === index ? mapper(it) : it);
 const lens = (key, mapper) => obj => ({ ...obj, [key]: mapper(obj[key]) });

 // somewhere
 this.setState(mapOne(1, lens("val", it => it + 1)));
```